# How to empty a Backbone.js collection

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I was surprised to discover that this doesn't work:

```
coll = new Backbone.Collection
for i in [1..1000]
  coll.add new Backbone.Model()

console.log coll.length # 1000
coll.remove coll.models
console.log coll.length # 500!
```

I understand why this strange result occurs, more or less, though it seems like a bug to me. In any event, what's the best alternative, without resorting to internal methods like `_reset` (which wouldn't work anyway, as I want the appropriate `remove` event to be triggered)?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to call [`.reset()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) on the collection.

> Calling `collection.reset()` without passing any models as arguments will empty the entire collection.

i.e.

```
collection.reset();
```

Comment: This will empty the collection on the client, not on the server.

Comment: Worth noting that as of Backbone 0.5.0, released today, `refresh` has been renamed [reset](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-reset) (a much clearer name, IMHO).

Comment: Note: `Collection.reset()` issues a single "reset" event at the end, per the docs. It _does not_ trigger "remove" events on the models that have been removed.

Answer (score 3):

Personnaly i use:

```
_.invoke(collection.toArray(), 'destroy');
```

wich delete every element of the collection by calling the *destroy* method

Answer (score 0):

The response marked as accepted is not complete, because `collection.reset` is a silent method and do not trigger the events that may you declare in order to clean your collection and/or models.

My approach is this:

```js
for (let i=0; i<collection.length; i++)
    collection.shift();
```

in this way the events are propagated

Answer (score -5):

The obvious answer is to clone `models`, e.g.:

```
coll.remove coll.models.slice(0)
```

This feels a bit hacky to me, but that may just be my own aesthetic.